# Maintain different versions of same file on Amazon s3 with "GET" parameters

Tags: amazon-s3, get

I have a scenario where I want to host different versions of my Javascript file on Amazon S3, which should all be available at the same time. Due to the constraints of my platform, I can only use 'GET' params to differentiate between these two files.

Ex.

```
https://s3.bucket.aws.com/bucketname/main.js?ver=1
https://s3.bucket.aws.com/bucketname/main.js?ver=2
```

How do I store these file versions?

Answer (score 1):

Turn on object versioning on S3, and you can retrieve a specific object version by adding `versionId=xxx` query parameter. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectVersions.html